# Best Method to Create and Use Customer Account Numbers in SQL Server 2008 SR2

Tags: sql-server, identity, sql-server-2008-r2, account

I am not a DBA so I am scratching my head a bit. I am trying to put together an application for the company I work for. I need to provide a unique customer account number for each office location my company conducts business with.

In the past, I have based customer account numbers off a primary keyed INT columns setup to use incremented identities. I am wondering if this is the best or even worse option for this type of information.

What would you recommend? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a natural key, if you can find one.  The problem with using meaningless keys is you can end up with duplicates that are difficult to recognize.

Comment: What do you mean by natural keys? At this point, the actual customer number that the users will see would be [Assigned Sales Rep Initials]-[Office-Identity Key] (ex JDO-15343).

Comment: A natural key is one defined by the business, as opposed to an application making one up.  Could you use your actual customer number as the primary or a unique key?

Comment: I planned to have the actual customer number come from the identity key of the Customer table as I can tell you right now that the business would not want to define its own (manually anyway).

Comment: No, I didn't mean the business defined the value manually, I meant the business knew what the key was supposed to be for each customer and could enter it themselves, as opposed to it being auto-generated by a database.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I must be tired or something.

Comment: You gave it to us, 15343.  You wouldn't want to include anyone's initials.

Comment: Ahh, ok. This would be their primary application so the business wouldn't have a customer number already in mind. They would enter the customer into the system (receiving an identity key from DB) and then assign it to a sales rep while entering in the other information. From this I would combine the sales rep and customer identity number and write that to a column in the customer table. This would allow them to search for it later/reference it on paper/invoices. The initials would not be part of the identity key btw. That is just how they identify it in office.

Comment: Yeah, I'd avoid that if you can, just because the system can't know if a customer's been created twice.  Consider using a main phone number, email address, taxID number, or something the business already has to track to distinguish them.

Answer (score 1):

We use an identity field for our accounts and user tables.  By and large the account & user ids are meaningless outside your application.  For example, few people care if their user id is 12345 or 1.

We're doing this on production websites.

Comment: Agreed. The account numbers will only be used as a reference on internal paper documents and QuickBooks invoices. A customer might refer to it once in a while, but my company is no where the size of a Verizon or TXU.